# Is there a native implementation version of Java Advanced imaging api?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, libraries, jai

Is there a native implementation of the java advanced imaging api?  We currently are using the jar files

1-jai_core-1.1.3.jar

and

2-jai_codec-1.1.3.jar

I have heard there is an implementation of this api written with native code that runs much faster but cannot find it on the mess that is Oracle's website.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "native implementation", are you talking native to the OS?  If so, which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are native JAI extensions for Windows, Linux and Solaris available here: http://download.java.net/media/jai/builds/release/1_1_3/

They do run a lot faster. AFAIK there are no native extensions for OSX.

Comment: Apple Inc. provides a Mac OS X version of the API from their website for Mac OS X v10.3; Mac OS X v10.4 ships with it preinstalled. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Advanced_Imaging :D)